# Is it a data-race when several thread *read* the same memory at the same time?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, data-race

cppreference.com [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#:%7E:text=When%20an%20evaluation%20of%20an%20expression%20writes%20to%20a%20memory%20location%20and%20another%20evaluation%20reads%20or%20modifies%20the%20same%20memory%20location%2C%20the%20expressions%20are%20said%20to%20conflict.%20A%20program%20that%20has%20two%20conflicting%20evaluations%20has%20a%20data%20race):

> Threads and data races
>
> *When an evaluation of an expression **modifies** to a memory location and
> another evaluation **reads** or **modifies** the same memory location*, the
> expressions are said to conflict. A program that has two conflicting
> evaluations has a data race unless...

This speaks about the scenario of 'thread1-modify thread2-read' (M-R) and about the scenario of 'thread1-modify thread2-modify' (M-M).

What about 'thread1-read thread2-read' (R-R)?

Comment: short answer is no. If you are just reading, there would be no race. But you have to be sure that you are ONLY reading.

Comment: Well, since it doesn't mention that situation in the context of data races...

Comment: In particular, as long as the data at that memory-location never changes, any and all threads can reliably read that location and see the same value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Multiple threads reading memory sequenced is not a data race as long as no thread is writing unsequenced in that memory location.

That scenario was probably left out of that description of data races, because that scenario is not a data race.